# Command script to Set Filenames to Variables

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to find a way to copy two *.log files into one file. My intent was to use For /R to set each filename to a variable.  Not as easy as I thought.  The log files will have different random names each week that I want to combine into one file called Kip.log.

I only got as far as:

```
FOR /R D:\Temp %F in (*.log) do echo %~nxF
```

I don't know how to get further.

Comment: Instead of using the ancient "DOS" command shell, consider learning PowerShell. It comes as part of Windows, and is far more powerful, and makes this sort of thing actually easy.

Comment: Do you really need to search sub-directories of D:\temp? It seems risky to me to assume that grabbing all *.log files under the D:\temp tree will give you nothing but the 2 that you need. You are assuming that prior week's files are always deleted, and that no unrelated .log files are ever created.

Comment: I'm hoping to port this batch file over to Powershell in the near future but right now I'm enhancing an existing batch file until I have time to move into PS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the two log files are in `d:\temp` then this will suffice.

```
@echo off
pushd "d:\temp"
copy *.log kip.txt
ren kip.txt kip.log
```

Comment: I didn't think I could use copy with asterisk.  KISS is good.

Answer (score 2):

If you can specify just the files you want using wildcards then this will work

copy *.log kip.log

or

copy a*.log+b*.log kip.log

Type copy /? for Help

Answer (score 0):

To set the variables (and then append) do this:

```
pushd D:\Test
dir /b *.log >> files.tmp
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
for /f %%a in (files.tmp) do (
set /a count+=1
set "file!1!=%%~a"
)
:: Now you have 2 variables (or more) all file[number]
:: Below is to append
copy "%file1%"+"%file2%" Kip.log
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
 FOR /r D:\temp %%F IN (
  zd*.*
  ) DO TYPE "%%~fF"&echo========%%~fF============
)>KIP.LOG
GOTO :EOF
```

You don't say why you need to set two variables; for the concatenation task, it's not necessary.

the `&echo========%%~fF============` above simply adds a separator with the filename found. It's not required and can be omitted if you wish.

If you "need" the filenames in variables simply to delete them, then

del /s d:\temp*.log

would make short work of that task.